# how to make regex in js

Tags: javascript

```
my_sty = "first = second * third"
```

i am trying to get `"second * third"`

how it possible through js regex

Comment: Try http://regexr.com. It's a great site

Comment: [JavaScript RegExp Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do with `split('=')` .And use the `trim()` for remove the unwanted spaces

```js
var my_sty = "first = second * third"
console.log(my_sty.split('=')[1].trim())
```

**Or** regex method try this pattern `/=(.*)/`

[Demo Regex](https://regex101.com/r/rDM22i/1/)

```js
var my_sty = "first = second * third"
console.log(my_sty.match(/=(.*)/)[1].trim())
```

Comment: none of your samples returns `"second * third"` which is what OP requested.

Comment: Are you target with `"` quotes @Wh1T3h4Ck5

Comment: no, I'm talking about extra space before word "second"

Comment: see the updated answer.is fixed by `trim()` @Wh1T3h4Ck5